# How to measure a person’s height like the Measure App from Apple?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, lidar

I'm trying to measure a person's height with the camera.
My first approach was to play with "[Capturing Body Motion in 3D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/capturing_body_motion_in_3d)" Sample Code in order to get some feeling about how it works.

To get the very top of a person's head, I calculated the *head_joint* position minus the *neck_3_joint* position. But for some reason, the height is no higher than 1.70m or so.

This is what it looks like:

```
   func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        for anchor in anchors {
            guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }
            
            let skeleton = bodyAnchor.skeleton

            let neckJointPos = skeleton.jointModelTransforms[49].columns.3.y
            let toesJointPos = skeleton.jointModelTransforms[10].columns.3.y
            let headJointPos = skeleton.jointModelTransforms[51].columns.3.y

            let crown = headJointPos - neckJointPos
            let height = crown + headJointPos - toesJointPos

            print(height) //always about 1.70m
        }
```

I also had the idea to create a bounding box around an object and just take the height, which might be the person's height. This is done similarly [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects). But looking at this project, I was just overwhelmed and didn't really know what I actually needed in order to use this for my simple project.

Any ideas how to do that? A push in to the right direction might also be very helpful

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you expecting? How tall is the test person. 1.7m is about average height

Comment: I tested this on a person that height was over 1.90m, and it always shows a max of 1.70m

Comment: Hopefully someone knows the project and is willing to help, I doubt somebody will examine the project for you and get the code you need. If it isn't worth learning for you it isn't worth learning for others.

Comment: I just want to measure a person’s height, that’s all, nothing else. But I'm stuck at this place where the measurement is not accurate enough for some reason. As mentioned in the first post. I'm open to other approaches to solve that measurement. Maybe I just started with the wrong one.

Comment: Hi, I know this is old but were you able to find the solution? If so, please post it here since I'm sure it would help many people (me included). Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Look into an AR Measuring app. It could have the accuracy you're looking for. Here's a course that creates one: https://www.udemy.com/course/building-augmented-reality-apps-in-realitykit-arkit/learn/lecture/32336678?start=0#questions

You can view it if you buy the course, which is only about $10 if you get the Udemy discount (worth it imo has a ton of insightful RealityKit tutorials and projects, but it's your money). You can try to find one on the web but that might take some time searching.